# Density APK splits does not reflect on mipmap folders

Tags: android, gradle

I have gone through APK Splits Concept from [From this example](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html#configure-split)

and I have tried to implement this in my project, but only `Drawable` folders have been affected. I want to also split `Mipmap` folders too.

Below is a snippet of code for my `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
. . .
    splits {
        density {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "mdpi", "hdpi", "ldpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"
        }
    }
. . . 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point behind `mipmap`, AFAIK, is so that those resources are not affected by APK splits. `mipmap` is used for launcher icons, and the home screen might elect to use a higher resolution icon than what ordinarily would be used for the screen density. Hence, APK splits ship all densities of `mipmap` resources, so the right ones are available for all devices.

If that is not what you want, get rid of the `mipmap` resources, replacing them with `drawable` resources.

Comment: Yeah, move all the mipmap file to drawable (except app launcher file ic_launcher.png) and it worked. But it looks ugly when I add .xml files and image file in one drawable folder